# Рендеринг HTML-элементов с помощью perspective?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Цель состоит в том, чтобы визуализировать элементы HTML в перспективе, как в примерах ниже.

Я попытался использовать правило  CSS `skew transformations`, но при этом  изображения выглядели неправильно, поскольку они искажали соотношение сторон элемента или иным образом создавали искажения.

Ниже в примере, CSS `skew transformation`, которые я использовал. Но, ни один из результатов не выглядит так хорошо, как на изображениях ниже.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMzdPx

```
transform: skew(20deg, -15deg);

transform: skew(45deg, -25deg);

transform: skew(45deg, -30deg);
```

Как  добиться такого рода перспективного рендеринга элементов HTML?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56948924/7394871

Comment: https://keithclark.co.uk/labs/css-fps/desktop/

Answer (score 4):

Как вы сказали, используйте перспективу в сочетании с некоторым вращением:

```css
img {
  width:150px;
  margin:20px;
}
img.first {
  transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(20deg);
}
img.last {
  transform:perspective(500px) rotateY(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/DGAOsPz.png" class="first">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/DGAOsPz.png" class="last">
```

```css
img {
  width:150px;
  margin:30px;
  transform:perspective(500px)  rotateY(15deg) rotateX(50deg) rotateZ(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/DGAOsPz.png" >
```

Смотри [связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51891329/8620333) для более подробной информации: